# Setting my GameWindow to fullscreen will stretch it to the desktop resolution

Tags: c#, opengl, fullscreen, opentk

Setting my GameWindow to fullscreen stretches it, how do I set it fullscreen without losing the original window resolution with the use of black bars?

This is my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Common;
using OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
using System.Drawing;

namespace OnlineGame
{
    public class Game : GameWindow
    {
        public Game(GameWindowSettings gameWindowSettings, NativeWindowSettings nativeWindowSettings)
             : base(gameWindowSettings, nativeWindowSettings)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Fullscreen;
        }

        protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            if (KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            {
                Close();
            }

            base.OnUpdateFrame(e);

            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
            GL.ClearColor(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            this.SwapBuffers();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GL.Viewport` to set the viewport rectangle to a sub-area of the window. "Copy" operations as `GL.Clear` are not affected by the rectangle of the viewport. Therefore, you also need to set a [Scissors Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Scissor_Test).

You need to know the current size of the window (`current_w`, `current_h`) and the original size of the window (`original_w`, `original_h`). Compute the aspect ration of the current window (`current_aspect`) and the aspect ratio of the original window (`original_aspect`):

```cs
double current_aspect = (double)current_w / current_h;
double original_aspect = (double)original_w / original_h;
```

Compute the sub-area and set the viewport and scissor rectnagle:

```cs
int w = (int)(current_w * original_aspect / current_aspect);
int x = (current_w - w) / 2;
GL.Scissor(x, 0, w, this.Size.Y);
GL.Viewport(x, 0, w, this.Size.Y);
```

---

Clear the entire window with the black color. Then restrict the viewport rectangle and enable the scissors test.
Note  you must set the clear color (`GL.ClearColor`) before the `GL.Clear` instruction.

```cs
protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
{
    if (KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
    {
        Close();
    }

    base.OnUpdateFrame(e);

    int original_w = ...;
    int original_h = ...;
    int current_w = this.Size.X;
    int current_h = this.Size.Y;
    double current_aspect = (double)current_w / current_h;
    double original_aspect = (double)original_w / original_h;

    GL.Disable(EnableCap.ScissorTest);
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, current_w, current_h);
    GL.ClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

    GL.Enable(EnableCap.ScissorTest);
    if (current_aspect > original_aspect)
    {
        int w = (int)(current_w * original_aspect / current_aspect);
        int x = (current_w - w) / 2;
        GL.Scissor(x, 0, w, this.Size.Y);
        GL.Viewport(x, 0, w, this.Size.Y);
    }
    else
    {
        int h = (int)(current_h * current_aspect / original_aspect);
        int y = (current_h - h) / 2;
        GL.Scissor(0, y, this.Size.X, h);
        GL.Viewport(0, y, this.Size.X, h);
    }
    
    GL.ClearColor(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

    // [...]    

    this.SwapBuffers();
}
```